# How do I annotate Git/SVN commit log in my source code in Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I used to be able to see who committed each line of the code in Xcode 4. Is this feature removed in Xcode 5?

Some people call this feature `Blame` view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. There used to be a button/shortcut for this in Xcode 4, I think. Now it's only in the menu item.

[image]

EDIT: You can also find it if you click and hold the version editor button:

[image]